# Check which printer is online

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, printer

I have one machine with Windows 7 - Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot, i installed and shared over the network my printer on every two operating systems, naming it printer-windows on w7 and printer-linux on ubuntu.

On another pc with Windows 7, i have added both printer-linux and priner-windows.

I don't know which operating system the server pc is running when i need to print some files, so is there a way to know which printer is really online on the Windows 7 client?

Comment: Neat question.  I would think the tray application would be aware of when each printer is offline, but maybe you need to query the properties of each to see.  I"ll be watching this question.

Comment: @RobertKerr I thought so, because offline printers are semi-transparent, but windows shows me all the 2 printers with the full colour, which means they are online, but in fact only one of them can be online...